# Unable to run native iOS App built with .net 6.0: libhostpolicy.dylib missing

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, .net-6.0

I am trying to build & run a native iOS application using .net 6.0.100 (RC1). I am **not** using MAUI. I am using both Visual Studio 2022 for Mac and Jetbrains' Rider. The application is a default one. The `.csproj` file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-ios14.0</TargetFramework>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <AssemblyName>Application.iOS</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Application.iOS</RootNamespace>
    <LangVersion>default</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I can successfully build the application but I can't run it:

```
Cannot use file stream for [/Users/xxx/Application/src/Application.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/net6.0-ios14.0/iossimulator-x64/Application.iOS.deps.json]: No such file or directory
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in '/Users/xxx/Application/src/Application.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/net6.0-ios14.0/iossimulator-x64/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because '/Users/xxx/Application/src/Application.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/net6.0-ios14.0/iossimulator-x64/Application.iOS.runtimeconfig.json' did not specify a framework.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in '/Users/xxx/Application/src/Application.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/net6.0-ios14.0/iossimulator-x64/Application.iOS.runtimeconfig.json'.
```

Here is the content of the file `Application.iOS.runtimeconfig.json`:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0-rc.1.21451.13"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.iOS",
        "version": "**FromWorkload**"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterInDesigntimeLicenseContextSerialization": false,
      "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsSupported": true,
      "System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Globalization.Invariant": false,
      "System.Net.Http.EnableActivityPropagation": false,
      "System.Net.Http.UseNativeHttpHandler": true,
      "System.Resources.ResourceManager.AllowCustomResourceTypes": false,
      "System.Resources.UseSystemResourceKeys": false,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false,
      "System.StartupHookProvider.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Threading.Thread.EnableAutoreleasePool": true,
      "System.Text.Encoding.EnableUnsafeUTF7Encoding": false
    }
  }
}
```

I know that the the `libhostpolicy.dylib` file exists in the `dotnet`'s installation folder. I copied the file over and got this error instead:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /Users/***/Application/src/Application.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/net6.0-ios14.0/iossimulator-x64/Application.iOS.dll
Cannot use file stream for [/Users/***Application/src/Application.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/net6.0-ios14.0/iossimulator-x64/Application.iOS.deps.json]: No such file or directory
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005
```

**Question**

How can I run a build / run native iOS application on .net 6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rider is not ready to run iOS app on .net6 yet. That being said, the application can be started by running the following command:

```
dotnet build -t:run
```